# Selective hover background change on nested divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on the following files:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #e4e4e4;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 40px 40px 40px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="d1" class="container">
        1
        <div id="d2" class="container">
          2
          <div id="d3" class="container">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result I want to achieve is that when I hover a certain div, its background changes to a `#ccc` grey color.

However what adds some difficulty is that I want only the area that belongs only to the innermost hovered div to change background color, not the child or parent.

Here is a picture to show the behavior I want for example when hovering the second div:

[image]

**EDIT: I ALSO WANT THE BACKGROUND COLOR TO BE RESET TO WHITE WHEN THE MOUSE IS OUTSIDE AN AREA**

**EDIT 2: IS THIS DOABLE WITH ONLY CSS OR IS JAVASCRIPT MANDATORY?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some magic using pseudo element and box-shadow:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #e4e4e4;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0; /* this is important */
  overflow:hidden; /* hide the extra box-shadow */
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 40px 40px 40px;
  position:relative; /* dont forget relative here */
  background:#fff;
}
.container::before,
.container::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:-1px;
  left:-1px;
  right:-1px;
  bottom:-1px;
}
.container::before { 
  background:grey; 
}
/* on hover */
.container:hover::after {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 200vmax #fff; /* hide the upper div */
}
.container:hover {
  background:transparent; /* make the hovered div transaprent to see the "before" element */
}
/**/
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="d1" class="container">
    1
    <div id="d2" class="container">
      2
      <div id="d3" class="container">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but the result is not perfect, I get a small white gap between a div grey applied background and its border.

Comment: I added it to my third edit, you see there is a gap between background and bottom border.

Comment: @Platus you have for sure zoom enabled, make sure it's disabled

Comment: How can I disable the zoom? I'm using chrome and I didn't apply any particular zoom (100%)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```js
const containers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.container')];

containers.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    if(containers.includes(container.parentNode))
      container.parentNode.classList.remove('hover');
    container.classList.add('hover');
  });
  
  container.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    if(containers.includes(container.parentNode))
      container.parentNode.classList.add('hover');
    container.classList.remove('hover');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #e4e4e4;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 40px 40px 40px;
  background: #fff;
}

.hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="d1" class="container">
        1
        <div id="d2" class="container">
          2
          <div id="d3" class="container">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```